# can we user ParseRelation for ParseObject in parse php SDK?

Tags: php, parse-platform

I am developing a web application in which I am using Bootstrap 3.3.2 for front and using parse php sdk https://www.parse.com/ as a database. In my application I am implementing simple Many to Many relation in which One **Doctor** has Many **Specializations** and vice versa.

I referred https://www.parse.com/docs/php_guide#objects-pointers (Relational data).In Doctor's table I created a column `Specialization_text relation<Specialization>` to find **a doctor has how many specializations?** and in Specialization table I created a column `Doctor relation<Doctor>` to **find this Specialization belongs to how many Doctors?**

I referred [using ParseRelation with ParseUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708697/how-to-use-parse-com-parserelation)  ,[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519123/parse-com-php-sdk-get-user-relations-for-object) etc. for **ParseUser**

In the documentation of parse php SDK [Example are given for Android and IOS](https://www.parse.com/docs/relations_guide)
but unable to find any proper example of using ParseRelation with ParseObject in PHP

Please suggest me any appropriate link or appropriate example in which ParseRelation is used with ParseObject using Parse PHP SDk.